# OnListItemclick only needs to respond on button press

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a listview with a custom adapter and implemented onListItemClick.
I have some components for each row and when clicking something in the row it launches an activity.
I wonder , how can I set that only if you click the button you launch the activity and not when randomly pressing in the row ?Or is it better to set onClick in the adapter itself for each button ?

Extends ListActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);

            Intent i = new Intent(LevelMenu.this,AreaMenu.class);
            i.putExtra("level_value", (pos+1));
            startActivity(i);



    }
}
```

Button :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/level"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/unlock"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="Play" />
```

Listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="15dp" />
```

Comment: hi i think this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134569/get-click-from-button-on-every-row-in-listview

Comment: set onclick Listener for your button in the customAdapter put your code there..

Comment: @David Is that button is inside the list view.

Comment: No it's inside my item layout .

Comment: You can set OnClickListener for that button you mentioned on your row, and remove onItemClickListener from your listView. So it'll launch only when you clicked the button.

Answer (score 0):

Without see how you're actually doing it, it may be difficult. What you can do, if you have just a general onClick, you can check to make sure that `View v` is `instanceof Button` then grab the id, tag, or whatever else from the button and use that to launch your activity.

```
public void onClick(View v){
    if( v instanceof Button){
        //a button was clicked!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an method `setEnable` in `baseAdapter` if you don't want `onItemClick` to be called just return false from this.

For your case pass one `boolean` value from `onClick` of your button and based on that you can return `true` of `false`.